# Running Matlab script as batch job in linux

Tags: linux, matlab, batch-processing

I'm trying to submit a Matlab script to a Linux server as a batch job but am not having any success so far. I'm very new to Linux so not sure what I'm missing, but I've tried every permutation I can think of.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#PBS -l walltime=1:00:00
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -o testscript.log
#
matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nodesktop -nosplash
run testscript.m
```

I've also tried these lines with the same header:

```
export SCRIPT="/panfs/panasas01/phph/testscript.m"
matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nodesktop -nosplash
$SCRIPT
```

And everything in between: with and without the **run** command, **.m, quotes, filepath** etc. The log file shows that Matlab opens but then can't find the command.

I've also tried opening matlab and typing:

```
batch('testscript')
```

I'm not sure if this command does what I'm looking for, but regardless it results in lots of error messages about not being able to find the variable `argsin`, along with

> 'Error using batch (line 172) Assignment has more non-singleton rhs
>   dimensions than non-singleton subscripts'

before the first line (simply a = 10) has even executed. The script runs with no problems otherwise.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Try this - `matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nodesktop -nosplash -r testscript`.

Comment: @Divakar You should add your comment as an answer so @neptune36 can accept it. That will mark the question as `anwered` and help other people find it!

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @Divakar in comment box:

Try this

```bash
matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nodesktop -nosplash -r testscript
```